# Nonlinear model fit output

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I'm trying to fit my data to function A.

```
z = 50;
s[x_] == (((q^2 (x/wr - wr/x)^2 + (z/(2 r) + 1))/(q^2 (x/wr - wr/x)^2 + (z/(2 r) + 1)^2))^2 + ((
 q (x/wr - wr/x) (z/(2 r)))/(
 q^2 (x/wr - wr/x)^2 + (z/(2 r) + 1)^2))^2)^(1/2);
A[x_] == 20*Log10[s[x]];

data = Import["C:\\Users\\Farzad\\Desktop\\ESR1.csv"];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
data, {A[x], q > 0, wr > 0, 
r > 0}, {{q, 9000}, {wr, 42000000}, {r, 0.1}}, x][
"BestFitParameters"]
Show[Plot[nlm, {x, 41000000, 43000000}, AspectRatio -> Full, 
PlotRange -> {{4.19*10^7, 4.25*10^7}, {0, -55}}], 
ListPlot[data[[All, {1, 2}]], PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]]
```

but for my output I get  the following:

[image: output]

I'm not sure what the problem is and why I don't get any values for my fit parameters.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should replace the `==` in `A[x_] == 20*Log10[s[x]];` with a single `=` (and follow @BobHanlon 's advice below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined `nlm` as rules for the parameters rather than the model

```
data = {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {3, 2}, {5, 4}, {6, 4}, {7, 5}};

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, x]["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 1.50632, b -> 1.42633} *)
```

Whereas, if you use parentheses to isolate the definition of the model

```
(nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, Log[a + b x^2], {a, b}, 
    x])["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a -> 1.50632, b -> 1.42633} *)

Plot[nlm[x], {x, Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4], Point[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Bob, even when I make that change I get the same output!

Comment: Did you change the argument to `Plot` to `nlm[x]` as shown?

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the error occurs because of the use of `==` in `A[x_] == 20*Log10[s[x]];`.  But I agree about the issue you found with the assignment of `nlm`.

Comment: @JimB - since the OP did not provide data, I was not able to run the code and did not notice the improper definitions of both `A` and `s`.